# Fibonacci sequence with other qualifications such as a limit and no shift functions

Tags: sequence, fibonacci

Does anyone have any tips on how I can start the assembly for this program?

Write a program to find and print a Fibonacci sequence of numbers. The Fibonacci sequence is 
defined as follows:

Your program should prompt the user to enter a limit, print the sequence up to the limit, and then 
indicate what is the greatest power of 2 that the final number printed is divisible by. Note: You 
are NOT allowed to use the divide function or any shift functions. If the number is odd, then the 
greatest power of 2 would be 2<sup>0</sup>
 = 1. Assume user input will be between 1 and 4096.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What language and environment are you using? Do you have any code to show and explain where you stuck or where the problem is? If answer to these questions is NO, then **no one here is going to do your homework for you.**

Comment: Assembly language.  Im asking for tips Im not asking for you to write my code.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have no problem in finding the fibonacci number in the given limit. Let it be n

I guess % should not be  used as it is closely related to /.

Now you can tr this (based on boolean properties)

1. Take a number t=1 and another ctr=0;
2. In a loop take n&t. if (n&t==0) {ctr++;t*=2;}else break the loop;
3. The final ctr value should be your answer

Comment: What if (n&2 > 0) and (n&4 > 0) and (n&8 > 0)? Will that mean that n is divisible by 8?

Comment: no if all n&1 n&2 n&4 are zero the number is divisible by 8 since these conditions imply that it has at least 3 ending zeroes in its binary representation

Comment: Yes, I did interchange the conditions earlier. Now it should be fine